# Magento get current product

Tags: php, magento, url-rewriting

I wanna check if the current product is disabled, redirect to its category url. Im using the method to get current product. However, it only seems to work for enabled product. If it's a disabled product in my case, a configurable product, it won't log its status. It only logs enabled product status "1" in the log file.

```
$product = Mage::registry('current_product');
$status=$product->getStatus();
Mage::log($status,null,'log.log');
```

It seems to me that I cant log any disabled product collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how it's supposed to work. If your product is disabled you cannot browse it, therefore Magento won't register it in 'current_product'.

To achieve this you must create your own module and add an observer for the event **catalog_controller_product_init_before** (it's the last event that is dispatched before you get forwarded to 'noRoute').
In the observer you must get the url params and based on those params you must load the product yourself (beware that the url can be /product.html or /catalog/product/view/id/XX and you must create cases for both scenarios). After that you can check if the product is disabled  or not and redirect the customer wherever you want.

Comment: That's exactly what we were trying. Thanks for the observer tip.